# Pytest: Finding when each test started and ended

Tags: python, testing, pytest, pytest-django

I have a complex Django-Pytest test suite with lots of tests that are running in parallel processes. I'd like to see the exact timepoint at which each test started and ended. How can I get that information out of Pytest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The start/stop timestamps for each call phase are stored in the [`CallInfo`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.runner.CallInfo) objects. However, accessing those for reporting is not very convenient, so it's best to store both timestamps in the report objects. Put the following code in a `conftest.py` file in your project/test root dir:

```
import pytest


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.start = call.start
    report.stop = call.stop
```

Now that you have each report enhanced with start/stop times, process them the way you need to, for example by printing them in a custom section after the test execution. Enhance your `conftest.py` file with:

```
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter):
    terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
    terminalreporter.section('start/stop times', sep='-', bold=True)
    for stat in terminalreporter.stats.values():
        for report in stat:
            if report.when == 'call':
                start = datetime.fromtimestamp(report.start)
                stop = datetime.fromtimestamp(report.stop)
                terminalreporter.write_line(f'{report.nodeid:20}: {start:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} - {stop:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}')
```

A test execution of sample tests

```
def test_spam():
    time.sleep(1)


def test_eggs():
    time.sleep(2)
```

now yields:

```
test_spam.py ..                                                         [100%]

------------------------------ start/stop times -------------------------------
test_spam.py::test_spam: 2020-04-26 13:29:05 - 2020-04-26 13:29:06
test_spam.py::test_eggs: 2020-04-26 13:29:06 - 2020-04-26 13:29:08
============================== 2 passed in 3.03s ==============================
```

Notice that in the above `pytest_terminal_summary` hookimpl example, I only print the time of the `call` phase (execution times of the test function). If you want to see or include the timestamps of the test setup/teardown phases, filter `terminalreporter.stats` by report objects with `report.when == 'setup'`/`report.when == 'teardown'`, respectively.

Comment: is there any way to take the timeout for workers, i am using extensively using -n=10 , but my setup is taking a lot time of in here while distributing tests to workers. i want to debug further and see why it is delayed. Actual test execution is faster but load schduling is taking a lot of time .

Comment: When I add these two functions to my `conftest.py` and run `pytest -v tests/`, I get `AttributeError: 'WarningReport' object has no attribute 'when'`

Comment: @SergeyZakharov IIRC `pytest` has no `WarningReport`s. Those may be part of some plugin installed in your environment - in this case, it is not compliant with `pytest.reports.BaseReport`. You can get around it by doing smith like `if getattr(report, 'when', None) == 'call': …`

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with an implicit fixture and the request fixture:

```
import pytest
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='function')
def implicit_fixture(request):
    log.info(f"{request.node.cls} {request.node.name} begin.")
    yield
    log.info(f"{request.node.cls} {request.node.name} end.")
```